# Add delay to print screen button in windows

Tags: windows

I want to keep using the `PrtScr` button to open Snipping Tool but I often touch it by accident.  I do not want to just disable it and have to use `Win + Shift + S`.  Can I somehow change the settings just for that one key to delay the acceptance of a click until its been held down for a full second?  Windows 11

Comment: I don't think so without affecting the entire keyboard.  Some apps have customization like this. Best thing, long haul, new computers - train yourself about using the keyboard properly. I do understand because I have the same tendency but no one is going to fix it for us.

Comment: Can't you press ESC to cancel the action? Eg. You press PrtScr, snipping tool opens, press Esc to cancel it? Don't know, I use Greenshot instead of snippingtool, there I can just abort with ESC.

Comment: Another long term way is to use WinKey + Shift + S for Snipping tool.  Very easy (one hand all keys right together) and avoids the PrtScr issue entirely. Works well for me. Remember that Microsoft tests all this in their labs in Redmond.

Comment: Put a bit of foam rubber under the key to make it a bit harder to press. On my PC's, I do that for caps lock, sO I DON'T SHOUT... oops

Comment: It might be simpler to install a third-party screenshot tool and disable PrtScr.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I'm terribly sorry. It was meant as a pun, but I missed the :P. Sorry. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Aight! :) Have a great day yourself. :)